# TDengine daemon core dumped

Tags: gdb, coredump, tdengine

Environment

```
OS: CentOS 7.9_x64
Memory, CPU, current Disk Space：Memory 96G， Disk 1T
TDengine Version：TDengine-server-2.0.20.13-Linux-x64
```

TDengine taosd daemon coredump.

gdb output:

```
[New LWP 5461]
[New LWP 5499]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/bin/taosd'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0 0x000056308db735cf in gcBuildQueryJson (pContext=0x7fdfdc0008c0, cmd=0x7fdfe00014a0, result=0x7fdfcc048ab0, numOfRows=682) at /home/ubuntu/workroom/jenkins/TDinternal/community/src/plugins/http/src/httpGcJson.c:154
154 /home/ubuntu/workroom/jenkins/TDinternal/community/src/plugins/http/src/httpGcJson.c: No such file or directory.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64
```

how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to resolve it?

It's a bug in TDengine-server. You don't "resolve" bugs.

You can try to figure out what the bug is (via debugging), or you can try newer version of `TDengine-server` (current appears to be `2.2.0.2`) and hope that the particular bug you've hit has been fixed.

Comment: thanks for your explain